# How to access Method of a Class in HTML Element using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Getting trouble in accessing `set_id` method inside `MyClass` class in HTML elemen button using TypeScript.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myClassObject.set_id(1)">Set ID</button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
class MyClass {
    set_id(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}
let myClassObject = new MyClass();
```

**Error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myClassObject is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):15)

By the way: I am new in TypeScript. hehe.

Can someone help me?

> Update: I'm using webpack to compile my TS

Comment: How is your Typescript getting put onto the HTML page? Are you using Webpack or something?

Comment: Cannot use typescript directly without compile it to javascript. Are you using any framework like angular? or using any build tools like webpack?

Comment: I'am using webpack.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765292/unexpected-modifying-of-the-js-by-webpack/59765377#59765377, but I can't VTC because answer isn't upvoted/accepted. In short, assign `myClassObject` to `window`, or - much better - set the handler properly using Javascript, rather than with an inline attribute

Comment: Inspect the generated JS code to find out why your example doesn't work.